# Why does stockfish suggest bishop pins on knights early on?

Tags: stockfish, bishops, pins

Stockfish suggests the following pin for me (white) against the queen on the night. However, whenever I play this move in real games black just kicks the bishop off with pawn to h6. I end up just wasting moves? Am I supposed to pin and then take? What is the point of that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this particular position, it's not so much that the pin is anything special; there simply aren't many squares where you can put your bishop that don't let your opponent double your pawns. The only other option would be Bxd6, which gives your opponent the pleasant choice of either developing their queen for free with Qxd6 or opting for controlling some central space with cxd6.

In this case, yes, you would take if they play h6, since retreating would again lead to Black doubling your pawns.

Note that your choice of Nxe5 also allows your opponent to double your pawns after ...Bxe5 Bxe5 Nxe5 dxe5.

Answer (score 1):

I kept misreading the question and thought you asked why black was pinning, but now I understand better.

I, and most high-ranked players, would accept the doubled pawns to get a pawns on e5.  This would provide a decent kingside attack, which would be better if you still had your light square bishop (LSB).

I do understand that your dark square bishop (DSB) is a (slightly) bad bishop, being obstructed by its own pawns.  The computer may be wanting to rid itself of this perceived weakness.

I little more than you asked, but I think deserve more insight into the position.  Enjoy my lichess friend.

My initial candidate moves are Qb5 (to weaken the queenside), h2 (to provide a safe square for the bishop), and c4 (to gain space on the queenside).  Secondary moves would be Nxc6 (to weaken the queenside again. but that strengthens the center, and Bg5 is no longer available) and just developing the queen's knight.